# Casting videos from one PC to multiple displays over an Ethernet Network

Tags: local-area-network, multicast, video-streaming

have a set of 6 television displays spread over 3 floors and a central personal computer at one of these floors. There exists an Ethernet cat6 cable network in the building with ports at the location of the displays and the PC. All these ports are connected to a 48 port Ethernet Switch. Is it possible to display different content on the displays at the same time controlled and displayed from the central PC? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated ..
I can add any hardware devices/components except a PC and I can run any software on the PC...no restrictions

I have explored HDMI over Ethernet extenders. However, the require separate PCs for all display and thus not feasible for my setup

Comment: Have you considered a Raspberry Pi or equivalent at each TV location?

Comment: Yes... I did get the idea from another forum. However, will it be possible to connect these raspberry pi's to my Ethernet switch and subsequently to my Central PC? I require a software solution to execute this setup

Comment: The Pi has both hardwired CAT6 and WiFi connections, and an HDMI connector for video. It runs a Linux variant, so there should be FOSS apps to do what you want. It does need power - an Android cell phone adapter is generally plenty for it.

Comment: You'd need a streaming client at each outlet. However, home computing/networking and product recommendations are explicitly off topic here.

Answer (score -1):

We are using a product called Monitors AnyWhere that will allow you to play multiple videos from a single PC over the network onto multiple screens:
https://monitorsanywhere.com/mawi-zero-7/